How to find linear equations of a SBox?
Given a SBox, how to determine if sbox is linear or not? If linear, how can we find the equations showing the linear relation between input and output bits of SBox. An example of linear SBox is given below copied from a CTF challenge.
I heard that LAT can help determine whether SBox is linear or not, but I was unable to understand its output.
If LAT can help, how can I create LAT and use it to determine if SBox is linear or not and if linear, what are the linear equations relating output bits of SBox with input bits.
$SBox = [105, 121, 73, 89, 41, 57, 9, 25, 233, 249, 201, 217, 169, 185, 137, 153, 104, 120, 72, 88, 40, 56, 8, 24, 232, 248, 200, 216, 168, 184, 136, 152, 107, 123, 75, 91, 43, 59, 11, 27, 235, 251, 203, 219, 171, 187, 139, 155, 106, 122, 74, 90, 42, 58, 10, 26, 234, 250, 202, 218, 170, 186, 138, 154, 109, 125, 77, 93, 45, 61, 13, 29, 237, 253, 205, 221, 173, 189, 141, 157, 108, 124, 76, 92, 44, 60, 12, 28, 236, 252, 204, 220, 172, 188, 140, 156, 111, 127, 79, 95, 47, 63, 15, 31, 239, 255, 207, 223, 175, 191, 143, 159, 110, 126, 78, 94, 46, 62, 14, 30, 238, 254, 206, 222, 174, 190, 142, 158, 97, 113, 65, 81, 33, 49, 1, 17, 225, 241, 193, 209, 161, 177, 129, 145, 96, 112, 64, 80, 32, 48, 0, 16, 224, 240, 192, 208, 160, 176, 128, 144, 99, 115, 67, 83, 35, 51, 3, 19, 227, 243, 195, 211, 163, 179, 131, 147, 98, 114, 66, 82, 34, 50, 2, 18, 226, 242, 194, 210, 162, 178, 130, 146, 101, 117, 69, 85, 37, 53, 5, 21, 229, 245, 197, 213, 165, 181, 133, 149, 100, 116, 68, 84, 36, 52, 4, 20, 228, 244, 196, 212, 164, 180, 132, 148, 103, 119, 71, 87, 39, 55, 7, 23, 231, 247, 199, 215, 167, 183, 135, 151, 102, 118, 70, 86, 38, 54, 6, 22, 230, 246, 198, 214, 166, 182, 134, 150]$

A simple method for an 8-bit $S$-box such as the example is to note the value S[0] if this is non-zero, then the $S$-box is definitely non-linear. However, you may still wish to check whether its affine and even isf S[0]=0 this does not imply linearity.
More carefully then, we can pick S[1] S[2], S[4], S[8], S[16], S[32], S[64] and S[128]. Then for each value 0-255 we check that the $S$-box value matches the XOR of the $S$-box value for each of its component bits e.g. for 77 we check
S[77] == S[64] XOR S[8] XOR S[4] XOR S[1] XOR S[0]
If each of these tests is true then the $S$-box if affine (and if true with S[0]=0 then it is linear.
Here's some python
for i in range(256):
    if SBox[i] != SBox[i&128] ^ SBox[i&64] ^ Sbox[i&32]^ SBox[i&16]^ SBox[i&8] ^ Sbox[i&4] ^ SBox[i&2] ^ Sbox[i&1] ^ SBox[0]:
        print(i)

If we run it on your SBox we see that your SBox is indeed affine, because no indices are printed.

Thanks for telling method to detect wether an SBox is linear or not. Mainly, i want to learn is  how to get those linear equations. like how to get output bit of SBox in term of input bits. I want to learn the method of finding those equations.

@AZANSHAHID If you have understood the method, the equations should be obvious.

Method of checking whether SBox is linear or not has already been described by @Daniel S.
Using sage, this can be achieved via the following code:
from sage.crypto.sbox import SBox

s = SBox([
105,121,73,89,41,57,9,25,233,249,201,217,169,185,137,153,104,120,72,88,40,56,8,24,232,248,200,216,168,184,136,152,107,123,75,91,43,59,11,27,235,251,203,219,171,187,139,155,106,122,74,90,42,58,10,26,234,250,202,218,170,186,138,154,109,125,77,93,45,61,13,29,237,253,205,221,173,189,141,157,108,124,76,92,44,60,12,28,236,252,204,220,172,188,140,156,111,127,79,95,47,63,15,31,239,255,207,223,175,191,143,159,110,126,78,94,46,62,14,30,238,254,206,222,174,190,142,158,97,113,65,81,33,49,1,17,225,241,193,209,161,177,129,145,96,112,64,80,32,48,0,16,224,240,192,208,160,176,128,144,99,115,67,83,35,51,3,19,227,243,195,211,163,179,131,147,98,114,66,82,34,50,2,18,226,242,194,210,162,178,130,146,101,117,69,85,37,53,5,21,229,245,197,213,165,181,133,149,100,116,68,84,36,52,4,20,228,244,196,212,164,180,132,148,103,119,71,87,39,55,7,23,231,247,199,215,167,183,135,151,102,118,70,86,38,54,6,22,230,246,198,214,166,182,134,150
])

#to check if sbox is linear or not
print(s.has_linear_structure())

We can use the polynomials function in the SBox class to get the linear equations.
s.polynomials(groebner=True)

This will return
[x0 + y4 + 1,
 x1 + y5,
 x2 + y6,
 x3 + y7 + 1,
 x4 + y0,
 x5 + y1 + 1,
 x6 + y2 + 1,
 x7 + y3]

These are the linear equations of SBox. Here y0,y1,...,y7 represents input bits and x0,x1,...,x7 represents output bits. Since, in this SBox, one bit of output depends on one input bit, you can just interchange x and y to get linear equations of output bits in terms of input bits where x and y represent input and output bits respectively.
If the output bit of SBox depends on multiple input bits, then you have to find the inverse of SBox. Now, get polynomials of inverse SBox using the code given above. In the resulting equations, interchange x and y. Now you have linear equations of the original SBox where each output bit depends on multiple input bits.
